# Mass to energy. Energy to mass?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, mass

As mass can be converted to energy does that equate to energy being a diluted form

of mass? If this is so could enough energy be created in a given area to counter

act a given outside gravitational force in theory?

Comment: William, look up Newtons Shell, if you don't already know about it, its a bit like your post https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem

Comment: @CounT101  Helpful but intuitively realized it and I had read something close.  I'm afraid where I am heading is very much taboo in the academia environment.  Energy acting like mass and possibly inversely so more like opposite ends of magnets.  It will be a costly uphill journey and no one of credential  would risk any credibility pursuing.  I have none of the latter so not so much to lose.   Can energy act like mass?

Answer (score 1):

Energy can't be created any more than mass can-- you have to move the energy from point A to point B, just like you'd have to move the mass.  Energy can only be converted from one form to another, locally.

Comment: I'm under the impression that energy very much so can be created from mass.  Now putting the genie back in the bottle, energy to mass may be a different nut.  Energy must move?  Potential energy?   Why not movement in a tight circle possibly simulating effects closely resembleing characteristics  more mass like?  If considering mass potential energy you are very much technically correct.